# Firefox Consumes A Lot Of RAM After Security Update

Tags: memory, cpu-usage, firefox-3.6

All was okay before 3.6.18 but after security update it started eating a lot of RAM and spiking frequent high CPU usage. Here are screenshots:

[image: RAM usage]

[image: CPU usage]

Currently have running Internet Explorer 8.0, Chrome 12.0.742.112 and Firefox 3.6.18.

Comment: Why not upgrade to Firefox 5?

Comment: 3.6 is now at its end of life..you should upgrade and that may fix it

Comment: Also, I hate to say it, FF3 is a memory hog. Looks annoyingly familiar to me.